# Trying to pull a variable only on row with max(date) while summing a different variable on all rows

Tags: oracle, aggregate-functions

I need to pull a value from the row that has the maximum date, while also summing all the values of a different column.

What I mean is something like this:

```
select

a.account_number,
a.client,
a.referral_date,
sum(b.amount),
max(b.date),
case when b.date = max(b.date) then b.due end as due

from a join b on a.account_number = b.account_number
group by a.account_number, a.client, a.referral_date, sum(b.amount), max(b.date), case when b.date = max(b.date) then b.due end
```

I'm sorry if this doesn't make sense, but I'm trying to sum ALL of "amount" while only getting "due" from the row with the maximum "date".

So if I join them so it only pulls max(date) I won't be able to sum ALL of the amounts.

I've been searching forever for this, but frankly I don't even know what to type into a search engine for this question.  Thank you in advance for your help!  Let me know how I can further clarify!

Steven

Comment: sorry for not trying to actually write the SQL...  you can do this by writing each part as a seperate query, then using each one in the FROM list, then joining to get one final row...

Comment: This would be clearer with some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work:

```
select a.account_number
     , a.client,
     , a.referral_date
     , sum(b.amount)
     , case when b.date = max(b.date) then b.due end as due
  from a join b 
    on a.account_number = b.account_number
group by a.account_number, a.client, a.referral_date
```

... and if you're using PL\SQL then untested but:

```
select account_number
     , a.client
     , a.referral_date
     , sum(b.amount)
     , max_date
 from ( select a.account_number
         , a.client,
         , a.referral_date
         , b.amount
         , max(b.date) over ( partition by a.account_number, a.client, a.referral_date ) as max_date
      from a join b 
        on a.account_number = b.account_number )
group by a.account_number, a.client, a.referral_date, max_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I precisely understand your goal, but how about this:

```
SELECT account_number, client, referral_date, amount, due
  FROM (SELECT a.account_number,a.client,a.referral_date, b.due, b.date TheDate
             , SUM(b.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY b.account_number) amount
             , MAX(b.date) OVER (PARTITION BY b.account_number) max_dt
          FROM a JOIN b ON a.account_number = b.account_number)
 WHERE TheDate = max_dt;
```